# How can I rotate labels with different angles in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, rotation

I am working on "wheel of fortune" kind of thing. I have a list for texts I want to see in wheel.

This wheel is working fine but I cant put list of my labels because of the angle issue.

I simply cant put labels with different angles with same origin in one class.

I can adjust the class(layout) angle but it is one time thing, I need to bind it to "for" statement.

I find a solution but not sufficient one. For each angle, I create a different class and put them one class on top of class.

The problem is the source of list may change and it must be bound to "for" statement as well.

Here is main.py :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import PushMatrix, PopMatrix, Rotate
import math 

am0=["Example1","Example2","Example3"] #HERE IS MY LIST

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


# ---------THIS PART IS FOR TURNING WHEEL ---------------------------------------------:
class Cark(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):

        y = (touch.y - self.center[1])
        x = (touch.x - self.center[0])
        calc = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
        self.angle1 = calc if calc > 0 else 360+calc
        self.mvmt = self.angle

        return super(Cark, self).on_touch_down(touch) 

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        y = (touch.y - self.center[1])
        x = (touch.x - self.center[0])
        calc = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
        angle2 = calc if calc > 0 else 360+calc

        self.angle = self.mvmt + (angle2-self.angle1)%360

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#AFTER THAT POINT I HAVE CREATE 3 DIFFERENT CLASS IN ORDER TO ADJUST DIFFERENT ANGLES;

class DayaI(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b1=Label(text=str("Example1"), pos_hint={'center_x': .8, 'center_y': .5},size_hint = (None, None))
        self.add_widget(b1)          
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rotation = Rotate()
            self.rotation.origin=self.center
            self.rotation.angle=45 # THIS ANGLE ADJUST LAYOUTS ANGLE
            self.bind(center=lambda _, value: setattr(self.rotation, "origin", value))            
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

class DayaII(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b1=Label(text=str("Example2"), pos_hint={'center_x': .8, 'center_y': .5},size_hint = (None, None))
        self.add_widget(b1)          
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rotation = Rotate()
            self.rotation.origin=self.center
            self.rotation.angle=0 # THIS ANGLE ADJUST LAYOUTS ANGLE
            self.bind(center=lambda _, value: setattr(self.rotation, "origin", value))  
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

class DayaIII(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b1=Label(text=str("Example3"), pos_hint={'center_x': .8, 'center_y': .5},size_hint = (None, None))
        self.add_widget(b1)          
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rotation = Rotate()
            self.rotation.origin=self.center
            self.rotation.angle=90 # THIS ANGLE ADJUST LAYOUTS ANGLE
            self.bind(center=lambda _, value: setattr(self.rotation, "origin", value))  
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# THE LOGIC I WANT WHICH IS NOT WORKING

class Day(FloatLayout): 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in am0:
            b1=Label(text=str(i), pos_hint={'center_x': .8, 'center_y': .5},size_hint = (None, None))
            self.add_widget(b1)          
            with self.canvas.before: # THIS PART DOESNT WORK BECAUSE IT ROTATES THE WHOLE WODGET
                PushMatrix()
                self.rotation = Rotate()
                self.rotation.origin=self.center
                self.rotation.angle=(360/len(am0)) #I WANT TO ADJUST ANGLE IN ORDER TO LENGHT OF MY LIST
                self.bind(center=lambda _, value: setattr(self.rotation, "origin", value))  
            with self.canvas.after:
                PopMatrix()


class MyyApp(App):
    pass

MyyApp().run()
```

here myy.kv :

```
MainWidget:
<MainWidget>:
    cark:cark
    Cark:
        id: cark
        size: root.size
        pos: 0, 0
        canvas:
            Rotate:
                angle: self.angle
                origin: self.center

            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0
            Ellipse:    
                size: min(self.size), min(self.size)
                pos: 0.5*self.size[0] - 0.5*min(self.size), 0.5*self.size[1] - 0.5*min(self.size)
        
## HERE IS 3 DIFFERENT WITDGETS LOCATED ON TOP OF EACH OTHER;        
    
    
        DayaI:
        DayaII:
        DayaIII:
```

Comment: Just use more than one Rotate instruction. What you have looks essentially correct - I'm not clear, are you saying this is the example that does not work? If not, please provide the example that you think should work but doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Yes, this example I have wrote works. But what if am0 lists has 20 items or more ? Should I add 20 or more layouts ? I want to make it in 1 layout. I want to bind; "text" and "rotation" to am0's lenght. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: The reason your not-working case doesn't work is that all the rotation gets added to canvas.before and all the widgets get added to canvas, so all the rotation code is run first then all the widgets are drawn with the same result. It might work if you change `canvas.before` to `canvas`. Alternatively, your workaround is fine but there's no need to make multiple classes, just make one to which the angle of rotation is an argument then instantiate it X times with X different rotations.